# scp using Jsch to copy file asking for password

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I am trying to copy files from one remote server to another remote. I tried to use scp. It's copying the files through putty but not through the code. I am currently using echo to copy the files. With echo I am writing a string `finalStr` to abc.bcc its working fine. But when using below command in Jsch its not working.

```
scp /home/abc.bcc user@host:/folder1/folder2/abc.bcc
```

I tried adding ssh public private keys but no luck. I tried with `channel.setPty(true)` to avoid password prompt and setting the password through bufferedWriter. But still unable to copy the files. Please suggest what needs to be changed.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session;
try {
    session = jsch.getSession("user", "host", 22);
    session.setPassword("password");
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    logger.info("Connection status: " + session.isConnected());
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(
            "echo \"" + finalStr + "\" >> /folder1/folder2/abc.bcc");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(false);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    channel.connect();
    logger.info("Channel status : " + channel.isConnected());
    out.write("\n".getBytes());
    out.flush();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
    int index = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info(++index + " : " + line);
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}catch(....
```

Debug output:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/build_path/.ssh/id1 
debug3: no such identity: /home/build_path/.ssh/id1: No such file or directory 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/build_path/.ssh/id2 
debug3: no such identity: /home/build_path/.ssh/id2: No such file or directory 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/build_path/.ssh/id3 
debug3: no such identity: /home/build_path/.ssh/id_3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you add some logs or console output? Also do you see any errors in the logs etc.

Comment: Add `-vvv` switch to `scp` for both scenarios and show us the output.

Comment: 1) *"for both scenarios"*, please 2) That's hardly a complete output. 3) Delete your unneeded comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The log looks like user home is not set correctly! So it doesnt find the key files!

General approach:

1. get the ssh to work without the code.
2. to copy from one remote to another requires the hostnames and connections to be resolved on both remotes for each other. so login to one remote and try the ssh connection from there directly to the other remote. This is not guaranteed to work.

I am pretty sure once you have this resolved you get everything else working.
When proxies are involved this can get quite complicated as the proxy settings have to work correctly between all 3 machines.
I am facing those issues repeatedly and it can be very messy.